# Counting unique elements in a table

Tags: date, google-sheets, unique, flatten, google-query-language

I have a table with names of players like this:

| Player |
| --- |
| John |
| Eric |
| Valerie |
| Carmen |

And another table with a list of played matches (match number, match date and the list of players that played in the match). Something like this:

| Match | Date | Player1 | Player2 | Player3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/11/2022 | John | Eric |  |
| 2 | 15/11/2022 | John | Eric |  |
| 3 | 15/11/2022 | John | Eric |  |
| 4 | 16/11/2022 | John | Valerie | Carmen |
| 5 | 16/11/2022 | John | Carmen |  |
| 6 | 17/11/2022 | John | Carmen |  |

Now with these information I would like to add a column to the player table showing the number of different days each player has played. Something like this:

| Player | Days (attendance) |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |
| Eric | 1 |
| Valerie | 1 |
| Carmen | 2 |

How can I do this?

My idea was:

- foreach player, select all records from the matches tables containing the player. For example with player Carmen I will select these:

| Match | Date | Player1 | Player2 | Player3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 16/11/2022 | John | Valerie | Carmen |
| 5 | 16/11/2022 | John | Carmen |  |
| 6 | 17/11/2022 | John | Carmen |  |

- from these records consider only the column date and and the column current player

| Date | Player |
| --- | --- |
| 16/11/2022 | Carmen |
| 16/11/2022 | Carmen |
| 17/11/2022 | Carmen |

- remove duplicates

| Date | Player |
| --- | --- |
| 16/11/2022 | Carmen |
| 17/11/2022 | Carmen |

- And finally count the number of elements

This was my idea but I'm a novice and I have not been able to implement it. How can I do this (or something similar)? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(IF(C2:E="",,B2:B&"​"&C2:E))), "​"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(<column of names here>, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(IF(C2:E="",,B2:B&"​"&C2:E))), "​"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label count(Col2)''"), 2, )))
```

Comment: Thank you Player0! I tried your code (without being able to understand it yet) and it generate a couple of columns: the players and relative attendance days. The value in the columns are correct (great!!) but I already have the list of players and I can't rewrite it. 

The code I need should write next each player (in the column beside) , the number of days. Or alternatively, how can I copy your results in my table according each player?

Comment: it looks there is one closing bracket at the end that should not be there. If I remove it I get the error "Wrong number of arguments to IFNA. Expected between 1 and 2 arguments, but received 3 arguments."

Comment: @G.Lari fixed, try now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
players['Days_Attendance'] = [list(matches['Player 1']).count(e) + 
list(matches['Player 2']).count(e) + list(matches['Player 2']).count(e) for e in 
players['Player']]
```

I do not know if you have a lot of columns "Planer n". If that is the case, you could think in create a function with the pourpouse of have a clean script.

Or, more complex for 12 players:

```
players['Days_Attendance'] = [sum(list(matches['Player ' + str(n)]).count(e) for 
n in range(1,12)) for e in players['Player']]
```

Regards,

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but I have no idea where I should enter your code. I just started using google sheet.